# Text classification 'features imput'

Tags: feature-selection, decision-trees, features

I have a text classification task that consists of classifying text into classes (literary genres).

I have computed the average word length and sentence length. Also, some POS relative frequency so that I can use these as features to train my model. I was thinking of using Decision Trees or another rule-based classifier. This is the first time that I created my own features for classification. Before, I relied on n-grams, vectorization, and BoW.

**My question is:** How can I use shallow features in text classification using `python`? I would like to know how the training set should look (in terms of features tabs in a csv file). Also, how can I instruct python to pick these features?

This a bit of a procedure question. Thanks.

Comment: not sure if I understand you correctly. But if you manually extract features and if you want to select meaningfull features, I would start with a multinominal logit with lasso or ridge. So you get an idea of what is really important...

Comment: Yes, the features I would like to train my classifier with are: avarage word & sentence length a long with TTR, but I am stuck at this point (feature creation) - I would like to do something like this in python: http://www.helsinki.fi/varieng/series/volumes/19/lijffijt_nevalainen/#appendix2